# string concat error: expected a literal

Tags: rust

So I have this:

```
struct User {
    reference: String,
    email: String,
    firstname: String,
    lastname: String
}

fn main() {

    let user = User {
        reference: "ref".to_string(),
        email: "em@ail.com".to_string(),
        firstname: "John".to_string(),
        lastname: "Doe".to_string()
    };

    concat!(&user.firstname.as_string(), " ", &user.lastname.as_string());

}
```

that's returning an error:

```
error: expected a literal
concat!(&user.firstname.as_string(), " ", &user.lastname.as_string());
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

But I thought that `.as_string()` already makes it a literal, does it not?  I am also finding `as_slice()` and `as_str()` references all over the place and it's confusing. Which one is it?

**UPDATE** OK, I was hoping I don't have to paste the whole thing here, but I guess I just have to do that anyway:

```
extern crate postgres;

use postgres::{Connection, SslMode};

struct User {
    reference: String,
    email: String,
    firstname: String,
    lastname: String
}

fn main() {

    let conn = Connection::connect("postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost/mydb", &SslMode::None).unwrap();

    let user = User {
        reference: "ref".to_string(),
        email: "em@ail.com".to_string(),
        firstname: "John".to_string(),
        lastname: "Doe".to_string()
    };
    let query = "INSERT INTO foo (user_id, name) VALUES ((SELECT id FROM user WHERE email = $1), $2)";
    conn.execute(query, &[&user.email, concat!(&user.firstname.as_slice(), " ", &user.lastname.as_slice())]).unwrap();

}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @DanielFath updated with context code

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are misunderstandings here.

`concat!` is a macro, that is a "code-generation" mechanism; as a result it is expanded at the first stages of the compilation, before type resolution/ownership checks/etc...

A literal is a value written *as-is* in the code: `true`, `1`, `"hello"`; the result of an expression *cannot* be a literal (by definition). The resulting types may look similar (or even be identical) but types are irrelevant here.

---

So, what do you really want? I guess you just want to concatenate strings. For `String`, you can just use `+`:

```
let fullname = user.firstname + " " + user.lastname;
conn.execute(query, &[&user.email, &fullname]).unwrap();
```

Alternatively, if you need some more complex formatting, you can use the `format!` macro (which does not require literals), here it would be:

```
let fullname = format!("{} {}", user.firstname, user.lastname);
```

Answer (score 3):

Rust `concat!` expects a literal as in a symbol literal (like `true`, `32` `'c'`, `"string"`) since it works in earliest parts of compile stages. During that time runtime value of types aren't resolved yet.

Based on your postgress example it seems like the best course of action is to simply create a function that returns full name or whatever you need:

```
struct User {
    ... //same
}

impl User {

   fn get_fullname(&self) -> String
   {
       let mut fullname = String::new();
       fullname.push_str(&self.firstname);
       fullname.push_str(" ");
       fullname.push_str(&self.lastname);
       fullname
   }
}

fn main() {

    let user = User {
        reference: "ref".to_string(),
        email: "em@ail.com".to_string(),
        firstname: "John".to_string(),
        lastname: "Doe".to_string()
    };
    let x = &[&user.email, &user.get_fullname()];
    conn.execute(query, &[x]);
```

I propose this, because it seems getting fullname is something you'll want to use often on your structs. However if not, you could format the values as Matthiueu M. suggested and just concatenate them assuming this is a one-time thing.

([Playground](http://is.gd/aEEMka))

Comment: To clarify: `concat!` does its job *entirely at compile time*; there's simply no way for it to join runtime values.  What you *want* is something like `format!("{} {}", first, second)`.