# Why the result of `Regex::new` cannot be assigned to a constant?

Tags: rust

I have many repeated constants in the form of:

```
pub const FOO_REGEX: Regex = Regex::new(r"foo.*").unwrap();
pub const BAR_REGEX: Regex = Regex::new(r"bar.*").unwrap();
```

I'd like to simply this by using a `macro_rules!` macro.

I tried:

```
macro_rules! pattern {
    ($value:literal) => {
        Regex::new($value).unwrap()
    }
}

pub const FOO_REGEX: Regex = pattern!(r"foo.*");
```

But the compiler complains with:

```
error[E0015]: calls in constants are limited to constant functions, tuple structs and tuple variants
  --> lib.rs:7:9
   |
7  |         Regex::new($value).unwrap()
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
...
11 | pub const FOO_REGEX: Regex = pattern!(r"foo.*");
   |                              ------------------ in this macro invocation
```

Per [this guide](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/macros/designators.html) I tried many of the available designators options, like `expr`, `ident`, but I'm still not able to get macro to compile.

Why does the `literal` designator not work for this macro expression?

Comment: What is the `Regex` you're using? I've tried to do this directly with `regex::Regex` and got the same error - https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c2a3394f6e3b8c54e8c6d1ee80a9d845

Comment: There are two questions in one, here: please choose whether to ask about `const Regex` or to ask about macro-literals. The title says one thing, but the bulk of the questions says another... If you have two separate questions, please simply ask two separate questions.

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with macros: you get the same error if you write the code directly ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=41fcd47adf1267f168e20b1594e515bd)). The problem here is that calling `Regex::new` is *not* a literal (1) and cannot be evaluated at compile-time ([yet?](https://github.com/rust-lang/regex/issues/607)). You will need to use something like the [`lazy_static`](https://crates.io/crates/lazy_static) crate to ensure that `Regex::new` is called at run-time to compile the regular expression:

```
use regex::Regex;
use lazy_static::lazy_static;

lazy_static!{
   pub static ref FOO_REGEX: Regex = Regex::new(r"foo.*").unwrap();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=00d0e7aed3667cca6769445cca0e4397)

---

**(1)** Quoting from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30481077/5397009):

> A literal is a value written *as-is* in the code: `true`, `1`, `"hello"`; the result of an expression [like `Regex::new`] *cannot* be a literal (by definition). The resulting types may look similar (or even be identical) but types are irrelevant here.

Comment: Or with [`once_cell`](https://docs.rs/once_cell/1.2.0/once_cell/unsync/struct.Lazy.html)

Comment: There's an issues on [rust regex GitHub](https://github.com/rust-lang/regex/issues/607) for it. Recently [String::new() and Vec::new() became const](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/50233) so it might be more doable now.